# Is WebAssembly slow with big functions?

Tags: javascript, emscripten, webassembly

Emscripten has a flag `OUTLINING_LIMIT` to get smaller functions which can be optimized by the browser's JIT, unlike huge functions which get interpreted. Is this also applicable for WASM, in the sense that will WASM with big functions be slower?

Comment: *"...which can be optimized by the browser's JIT, unlike huge functions which get interpreted..."* What makes you think large functions are *interpreted*? There are many advantages to smaller functions, but that doesn't mean big ones don't get compiled.

Comment: To answer your question, no, WebAssembly is not slow with big functions.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, *What do JavaScript engines do with very large functions? Generally speaking, since compiling them takes very long, JITs have just not fully optimized them and left them in the interpreter or baseline JIT*, from [here](http://mozakai.blogspot.in/2013/08/outlining-workaround-for-jits-and-big.html), referenced from emscripten's docs

Comment: @ColinE any reference for this?

Comment: Thanks. I wonder if that post was correct in 2013, and wonder even more if it's still correct in 2018. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation you quote is inaccurate for current implementations of WebAssembly. Only Chakra has an interpreter right now, and any "hot" function gets JIT-compiled regardless of size. The JavaScriptCore implementation of WebAssembly only JIT-compiles, and "hot" functions get re-compiled at a higher optimization level.

That being said, outlining has a few advantages:

- The `.wasm` binary can get smaller. That means it downloads faster.
- In theory, engines could re-inline small outlined functions if we start seeing them a lot on the Web, so you wouldn't get a performance loss from outlining.
- Big functions sometimes take longer to JIT-compile, often compilation is non-linear (though again, engines change over time and could handle large functions better if that becomes a widespread problem).
- Engines often compile in parallel at a per-function boundary, so more small functions compile in parallel better and fill up the compilation pipeline more (especially towards the end of compilation, if you had only a few large functions left to compile your cores wouldn't be utilized). This is a pretty minor point, I wouldn't worry about it much.

All this is in flux though, engines implementors react to what we see on the Web, and tune the engine to better handle real-world code. It's often good to do what's right, and file bugs on each engine if you see pathologies. Here that might mean reducing download size by using outlining, and expecting good re-inlining to occur.